# Android Studio, how to add my own git repository as a library project(sub module)?

Tags: android, eclipse, git, android-studio, build.gradle

I am new to Android Studio, Right now I have create a project and added a module in it as a library project but when i push the project to Git the library project gets also added to the repository instead in other new Git repository.

I just want to know that how can i create a sub module in Android Studio like we do in Eclipse via egit plugin, and how to push it to a completely new Git repository, practically this sub module would actually be my library project.

Comment: You can use git submodule.

Comment: @dannyroa but i am confused how to implement it actually in Android Studio, can you explain in detail.

Comment: You can't set it up within Android Studio. You have to set up the git submodule on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

i also had the same situation where i had to develop a library and the application in parallel. 
For this you can use android library project as git submodule to your application project, in that way you can manage both your application project and the library project.So here is my solution:

Step 1: create an android library project.

its similar to creating normal application project. just go through this google doc : https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html

step 2: create a repository for the library project in git (GitHub/BitBucket)

step 3: add the library codes to the version control system (VCS)

[image: android studio adding codes to VCS]

step 4: push your library codes to the git repository

[image: pushing code to git]

Step 5: now create your Android application project

Step 6: Add the project to version control system (VCS)

Step 7: From the bottom version control menu, add all the Unversioned Files to the VCS

[image: adding un-versioned files to vcs]

Step 8: From android studio project terminal add git sub-module using command

```
git submodule add HHHH://XXX@bitbucket.org/YYY/ZZZ.git

make sure the sub module save location folder name is different than the original library project name, else you might get conflicts.
```

Step 9: You will get a message for 'unregisterd vcs root detected'. click on add root

[image: un-versioned vcs root detected popup]

now you can see multiple git repositories at the right bottom of the android studio

[image: multiple git selection available]

Step 10: goto file menu — project structure

Step 11: click ‘+’ on left top

[image: adding new module]

Step 12: select ‘Import Gradle Project’

[image: importing library project]

Step 13: select the sub-module folder

Step 14: give the actual sub-module project name

[image]

Step 15: Sync

Step 16: Now in the application project builg.gradle file add

```
compile project(‘:lib-name’)
```

within the dependencies section

Step 17: gradle sync & build project

Now you have an application project in git, which uses a library which is added to it as a submodule in git. Now you can develop on the application and on the library parallelly. Its better to keep a separate branch of the library for an application so as not to conflict with other application usage, and if the library code changes can be used in other projects also you can make a PR request to the main branch of the library.

Happy Coding :)

I have published this as my blog:
https://medium.com/@deepakpk/how-to-add-a-git-android-library-project-as-a-sub-module-c713a653ab1f#.mt6dlng5n

Comment: Please don't just include a link to the solution - explain the solution in the post. Also you should probably disclose if this is a link to *your* website

Comment: Still working very well. Thanks, i have not find anything else explaining how to do this.